# 'fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0'

Tags: ios, swift, plist

What does this error mean?

[image]

When I run my project at 'ProjectA...eter' I can share to FB.

But when I run it at 'ProjectA...Checkin' the error appeared

Anybody helps me about this error.

Thank you for supporting me

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `fbauth2` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` array in your app's info.plist file. Apple made it so that apps need to whitelist the URL schemes that they'll attempt to call `-canOpenURL:` on in iOS 9 and above under the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key, and it sounds like the SDK you're using requires it. For more info see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW14).

Answer (score 0):

You Have to register Your App on The Facebook 
From There You will get a Code and you have to copy the Code and paste in info.plist File .
Register Your App  Click the Link Below.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

Hope it Helps